# O que é BFF (Back-end For Front-end)?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software

Este é um termo que já me deparei diversas vezes e, recentemente, vi que este termo foi citado como requisito para uma vaga de emprego para um dev júnior. Não sei se isso seria um absurdo, exigir conhecimento ou não de um dev iniciante pois não sei nada sobre o assunto. Não sei se é algo que envolve engenharia da software, formas de desenvolver uma aplicação *server-side*, etc...

Gostaria de saber do que se trata este termo **Back-end For Front-end**.

- Do que se trata?
- É um padrão de arquitetura?
- Quando usar?
- Um dev *fullstack* ou *back-end* deve conhecer a lógica, conceito e implementação às quais este termo se refere?

Comment: Não entendi o negativo, trata-se de arquitetura BFF de microsserviços dá excelentes respostas e as perguntas são quase um roteiro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Conceito

A experiência dos usuários ao utilizar navegadores web pode variar muito de um dispositivo para outro - podemos utilizar um celular como exemplo, que possui uma dinâmica de navegação completamente distinta de desktops e notebooks; isso significa que precisamos adicionar funcionalidades nas APIs de backend para que elas também possam suportar celulares. Porém existe diversos dispositivos e se tentarmos adaptar as APIs para todos eles, poderíamos comprometer a aplicação inteira.

O BFF é uma solução para contornar esse problema, ou seja, **a ideia é criar uma API para cada interface de usuário**, em outras palavras, um backend para cada frontend - desfrutando assim de toda a capacidade do dispositivo utilizado - e não uma API de uso geral. Eu encontrei uma imagem que ilustra bem isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou dar um exemplo:

Um dispositivo mobile é limitado comparado ao um computador. Dado essa informação, quero que imagine dois usuários, um está utilizando um desktop, o outro está utilizando um celular. Ambos estão fazendo a mesma requisição em um site que utiliza uma API geral. O usuário que está utilizando o desktop, terá uma resposta mais rápida, isso porque o computador conseguirá "digerir" todos os dados primeiro.

Agora quero que imagine que esse mesmo site possui uma API dedicada para cada dispositivo. Concorda que o tempo de resposta para essa requisição vão ser bem semelhante? Isso ocorre porque a API se torna menos complexa e por ser totalmente dedicada a um dispositivo. Além disso, a API do celular pode acionar funcionalidades que somente dispositivos mobiles possuem (como um leitor de código QRcode).

## Autonomia

Freqüentemente, vemos situações em que uma equipe está trabalhando em um front-end e outra equipe está criando os serviços de back-end. Em geral, estamos tentando evitar isso mudando para microsserviços que estão alinhados em torno dos setores de negócios, mas mesmo assim há situações em que isso é difícil de evitar. Em primeiro lugar, em um determinado nível de escala ou complexidade, várias equipes precisam se envolver. Em segundo lugar, a profundidade das habilidades técnicas necessárias para executar uma boa experiência em Android ou iOS geralmente precisa de equipes especializadas.

Portanto, as equipes que criam interfaces de usuário são confrontadas com a situação em que estão chamando uma API que outra equipe está conduzindo e, frequentemente, a API está evoluindo enquanto a interface de usuário está sendo desenvolvida. O BFF pode ajudar aqui, especialmente se for propriedade da equipe que está criando a interface do usuário. Eles evoluem a API do BFF ao mesmo tempo em que criam o front end. Eles podem iterar ambos rapidamente. O próprio BFF ainda precisa chamar os outros serviços downstream, mas isso pode ser feito sem interromper o desenvolvimento da interface do usuário.

[image: 1]

O outro benefício de usar um BFF alinhado aos limites da equipe como este é que a equipe que cria a interface pode ser muito mais fluida ao pensar sobre onde reside a funcionalidade. Por exemplo, eles podem decidir empurrar a funcionalidade para o lado do servidor para promover a reutilização no futuro e simplificar um aplicativo móvel nativo ou para permitir o lançamento mais rápido de uma nova funcionalidade (já que você pode ignorar os processos de revisão da loja de aplicativos). Essa decisão pode ser tomada pela equipe isoladamente, se ela possuir o aplicativo móvel e o BFF - não requer nenhuma coordenação entre equipes.

## Quando usar

Para um aplicativo que fornece apenas uma IU da web, suspeito que um BFF só fará sentido se e quando você tiver uma quantidade significativa de agregação necessária no lado do servidor. Caso contrário, acho que outras técnicas de composição de IU podem funcionar tão bem sem exigir um componente adicional do lado do servidor.

No momento em que você precisar fornecer uma funcionalidade específica para uma interface de usuário móvel ou de terceiros, eu consideraria fortemente o uso de BFFs para cada parte desde o início. Eu poderia reconsiderar se o custo de implantação de serviços adicionais é alto, mas a separação de preocupações que um BFF pode trazer torna uma proposta bastante atraente na maioria dos casos. Eu estaria ainda mais inclinado a usar um BFF se houver uma separação significativa entre as pessoas que criam a IU e os serviços posteriores, pelos motivos descritos acima.

Eu particularmente utilizei essa arquitetura pouquíssimas vezes, porém se você quiser ser um bom desenvolvedor backend, é recomendado ter pelo menos uma noção de BFF. Muitas empresas utilizam esse padrão, como a SoundCloud e Reddit.

Fonte:

- [Pattern: Backends For Frontends](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/)

Comment: Vou dar uma lida  no blog com calma depois, mas acho que dá pra melhorar ainda mais sua resposta. Depois eu coloco umas info a mais que deu pra perceber que tem no blog.

Comment: Certo, esperarei.

Comment: Eu adicionei alguns trrechos do artigo que achei relevante para incluir na resposta. Me diga o que acha e se quiser pode fazer os ajustes necessarios :)

Comment: Ficou show! Obrigado pelos ajustes xD